# How to have interaction behavior work on a UserControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, attachedbehaviors

I have the following UserControl that has an attached behavior on it. At the moment I have to select one of the DataGrid items in order for it to run the behavior.

Only guessing here but it's kind of understandable because these containers are not focusable or are not supposed to register keyboard events, so it goes to the next child available???

I could place this functionality on the window however this UserControl can get swapped out with another UserControl and I prefer for it not be be lying around. 
This is just a unique case in my app where the only thing on the window is the DataGrid and I don't necessarily want to select a DataGrid item to begin the behavior.

My question is: Is it possible to get the following behavior to work? Either on the UserControl, Grid or maybe some other control that would permit this.

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserManagement.LaunchPad"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:helpers="clr-namespace:UserManagement.Helpers"
             xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
             xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <helpers:OpenPopupBehaviors FindPopupObject="{Binding ElementName=PopupFind}" 
                                    GotoPopupObject="{Binding ElementName=PopupGoto}" />
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>

    <Grid>
        <DockPanel>
            <DataGrid />
        </DockPanel>
        <Popup Name="PopupGoto" />
        <Popup Name="PopupFilter "/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Here is the behavior:

```
class OpenPopupBehaviors : Behavior<UserControl>
{
    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        this.AssociatedObject.KeyDown += _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        this.AssociatedObject.KeyDown -= _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
    }

    void _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.F && (Keyboard.Modifiers & (ModifierKeys.Control)) == (ModifierKeys.Control))
        {

            var popup = FindPopupObject as UserManagement.Controls.NonTopmostPopup;
            if (popup == null)
                return;

            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }

        if (e.Key == Key.G && (Keyboard.Modifiers & (ModifierKeys.Control)) == (ModifierKeys.Control))
        {
            var popup = GotoPopupObject as Popup;
            if (popup == null)
                return;

            popup.IsOpen = true;
        }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty FindPopupObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("FindPopupObject", typeof(object), typeof(OpenPopupBehaviors), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object FindPopupObject
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(FindPopupObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(FindPopupObjectProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty GotoPopupObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("GotoPopupObject", typeof(object), typeof(OpenPopupBehaviors), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public object GotoPopupObject
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(GotoPopupObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(GotoPopupObjectProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I can see is that the focus if your issue

you can make use of `Preview` events to receive the events even if the focus is on control's child or their descendants

```
protected override void OnAttached()
{
    base.OnAttached();
    this.AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown += _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
}

protected override void OnDetaching()
{
    base.OnDetaching();
    this.AssociatedObject.PreviewKeyDown-= _KeyBoardBehaviorKeyDown;
}
```

I have changed `KeyDown` to `PreviewKeyDown`

above solution will work as long as the `AssociatedObject` have focus on it or any child within it. if you look forward to control it globally then perhaps you may need to attach the events to top level elements eg. `Window`

so in order to do that you need to find the appropriate parent of `AssociatedObject` and attach the event to the same.

also make sure that the following cast is valid

```
FindPopupObject as UserManagement.Controls.NonTopmostPopup;
```

it could be

```
FindPopupObject as Popup;
```

Comment: I also added Focusable="True" to the UserControl to see if that made a difference. Unfortunately when the screen first loads and I press Ctrl + f nothing happens, but when I select an item it opens the Popup.

Comment: Focusable just enable that it can be focused. what you can do is to set `FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` in the element of `LaunchPad` in main window. that will help you focus the control. if still does not work then attach the events to parent window instead of user control.